# Why 'mouseenter' event does only works for the first element of a spacebar #each iteration?

Tags: javascript, css, meteor, mouseenter, spacebars

I am trying to make an off-canvas menu in a template component. I took [this article](https://scotch.io/tutorials/off-canvas-menus-with-css3-transitions-and-transforms) as reference.

I have a very common setup:

- One container tab where I iterate on an `items` collection
- One `item` component where I have my off-canvas menu

In other terms, I have a spacebar iteration on my `items` cursor in my container:

```
{{#each items}}
  {{> item}}
{{/each}}
```

and in my `item` component, I have a simple `mouseenter` event attached to a `<a>` DOM node.

```
Template.item.events({
  "mouseenter  #item_menu": function(event, template){
    console.log("hover detected");
    $(template.find('#item_wrapper')).toggleClass('show-nav')
  },
})
```

It works perfectly well with the first `item` component but for all the others, the `mouseenter` event is not triggered. Why?

Comment: Dont use ids for your selectors because they should be unique, use classes instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the element and the event selector from `#item_menu` to a class `.item_menu` ID should be unique (once in your html)

Comment: It works, thanks! I expected the uniqueness of `id` selector to be respected since each similar `id` is in different template. Looks like I was wrong. :)